# Insert timestamp into PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to insert TIMESTAMP into column LAST_LOGIN

```
CREATE TABLE USER(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT,
 FIRST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_LOGIN DATE,
 DATE_REGISTERED DATE,
 ROLE INTEGER,
 CAN_LOGIN INTEGER
)
;

ALTER TABLE USER ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE USERS SET LAST_LOGIN = TIMESTAMP WHERE USER_NAME = ?
```

But I get `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "timestamp" does not exist Position: 31`

What is the correct way to insert current time into table column LAST_LOGIN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP` is not a known function is `POSTGRES` , therefore, it recognize it as a column .

`POSTGRES` dates/time functions:

```
NOW();
current_date;
current_time;
current_timestamp;
```

So your correct query should be

```
UPDATE USERS SET LAST_LOGIN = now() WHERE USER_NAME = ?
```

[You can read all about postgres time/date functions in this document.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Ok, can I use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Oracle Timestamp?

Comment: Now() returns `TIME STAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, note that according to his table `LAST_LOGIN` column is of type `Date`.  This won't make much of a difference for this specific query but it is better to use `current_date`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error comes from using the wrong function. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE USERS SET LAST_LOGIN = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE USER_NAME = ?
```

Comment: @Peter Penzov, even if my answer is earlier, set sagi's answer as accepted since it's more detailed and has correct referencing.